# hidden element showing height issue?

Tags: jquery

As I am hiding #parent element it will disappear from page, but still showing height as written in alert.

What jquery/css code I should use to get zero height of hidden element, I got some answered like hidden element is still on page so showing height.

If it is true, then please tell me alternate way to get height zero for hidden element, I need this for some UI project actually I am subtracting hidden element height from window height to set Google map height.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="target" style="height:100px;">

    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($("#target").height());

    $("#target").hide();

    alert($("#target").height());
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hiding an element don't change any other properties, than adding `display: none` to the element style. If you want the height to be 0 when hiding, you should `.height(0)` on that element.

Comment: How is this causing you an issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the element is hidden on the page and if the element is hidden then you can use a height of 0.

```
var height;
if ($("#target").is(":hidden")){
 height = 0
//Other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <div id="parent">
  <div id="target" style="height:100px;">

</div>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


    alert($("#target").height());



   $("#target").hide();



    alert(document.getElementById('target').clientHeight);


});
</script>
```